# Чем заменить перебор?

Tags: python, олимпиада

Недавно ездил на олимпиаду, и там была задача:

> На вход поступает 3 положительных натуральных числа, `l` `r` `a` Нужно найти сколько пар чисел от `l` до `r` (включительно) можно составить, но сумма этих 2 чисел должна быть кратна числу `а`.
>
> Например: на вход идут 3 числа 1 5 2. На выход 4. Так как можно составить 4 пары [1, 3](1+3=4. 4 делится на 2 без остатка)[1,5][2,4][3,5].

Если решать эту задачу перебором, то при больших числах программа превышает лимит времени. Видел как кто-то решил данную задачу математически, но постеснялся узнать подробности.

Comment: А почему в результате нет пар [1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4] и [5,5]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Находим остатки от деления

```
lm = l % a
rm = r % a
```

И частные, округленные вверх для нижней границы и вниз для верхней

```
lq = (l + a - 1) // a
rq = r // a
```

Если `rq > lq`, то промежуток `a*lq..a*rq-1` содержит все возможные остатки `0..a-1` в количестве `rq-lq` раз каждый, и ещё имеются остатки в диапазонах `lm..a-1` и `0..rm`

Зная количество разных остатков, можно найти количество их попарных сумм, дающих `0 
 или a`

Для приведённого примера остаток 0 встречается 2 раза, остаток 1 - 3 раза. Количество пар для остатков `q` и `a-q` будет `N(q)*N(a-q)` или `N(q)*(N(q)-1)/2` в случае `q=a-q` или `q=0`, т.е. здесь `2*1/2 + 3*2/2 = 4`

Для промежутка 2..11 и a=3  ответ будет `3*2/2+3*4=15`, a для a=4 `2*1/2+3*2/2+3*2=10`

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из того, что в ответе в парах одно число всегда меньше другого могу предложить такой вариант.

1. Перебираете в цикле все значения `i` от `l` до `r-l`.
2. На каждом шаге:

   2.1. находите такое минимально `j`, что `i`<`j`<=`r` и `i+j` кратно `a`.

   2.2. Перебираете все числа `j`, `j+a`, `j+2a` ... `j+na` до тех пор, пока `j+na` <= `r`. Пара [`i`, `j+na`] и есть искомая пара.

Если нужно только количество, то вычислить `j` и `n` можно математически.